Question about the sun and moon
Im confused about these verses
Quran 71:15
Do you not consider how Allāh has created seven heavens in layers
Quran 71:16
And made the moon therein a [reflected] light and made the sun a burning lamp?
does the word "fihinna" or "فِيهِنَّ" meaning "in them" mean that the sun and moon light up all the 7 heavens
because the heavens are mentioned, then the sun and the moon are mentioned to have light in them (in the heavens)
i dont understand
